# How to make a button invisible in odoo 11

Tags: odoo

I did something with the website module and suddenly in the Contacts module in the form appeared a smart buttom with the word "Not published" and below "on the website". Iam is working with Odoo 11

I want that smart button not to appear anymore.

Comment: You did something with the website module... such as installing that module? When you install the website module some views get modified and a Published/Not Published button is added to the form view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it permanently you can use invisible="1" using XPath
like:

```
<xpath expr="//form/button[@name='btn name']" poosition="attributes">
 <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```